# Standalone XULRunner Application on Mac OS X 10.5 Error

Tags: macos, xul, xulrunner

I'm new to Mac OS. I've developed a standalone XULRunner application that runs with no issues on both Windows and Linux. Mac OS X 10.5 is giving me issues, however. I downloaded the XULRunner runtime from [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/11.0b8/runtimes/xulrunner-11.0b8.en-US.mac-pkg.dmg). Running `/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin` with no switch displays the help screen. But it fails with an `<Error> - </Error>` when run with any other switch.

I've tried all manner of tricks but no success so far. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you running a beta version of XULRunner? The [same directory](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/) currently has XULRunner 11.0 and 12.0 which are stable versions. Also did you try running it with `-app foo.ini` switch (where `foo.ini` is the path to your application's definition)?

Comment: Thanks Palant for the prompt response. Yes, I ran it with the `--app` switch, but it failed silently; no error displayed. Thanks for the pointer on the version. Let me try a stable version. I'll post my findings here after testing.

Comment: I don't think that XULRunner would ever fail silently - it rather sounds like it started your application but it didn't open any windows for some reasons.

Comment: I'm rather new to Mac. Today is my second day at Mac OS. How do I find out if it started the application but was unable to display any GUI elements? May be an error log location, or something of the sort.

Comment: I know nothing about Macs. But you might want to try `-jsconsole` switch (after the `--app` switch), maybe the Error Console will open.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I've downloaded version 11.0 stable of XULRunner runtime. When I run `/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin --app $PWD/application.ini`, it fails with the following error: `dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022`. Actually, even the originally haven't changed.

Comment: See http://asqueella.blogspot.de/2010/12/dyld-unknown-required-load-command.html (first search result on Google).

Comment: Palant, you've been very helpful. I'd seen info at that link. When tried with the `arch -i386` option, it failed with no error displayed, even if I use `-jconsole` switch. If I run xulrunner-bin without the `arch -i386` option, it fails with `unknown required load command....`. The options detailed towards the end of the blog entry requires recompiling XULRunner, which I think I'll only do when everything else can't work.